# Post to facebook without showing application name

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to write some facebook application that allows a user to post to his own wall. I am using essentially the following code:

```
    $request = new FacebookRequest(
                                $session,
                                'POST',
                                  "/mefeed",
                                array ('message' => $msg,'link' => $link)
                                    );
    $response = $request->execute();
    $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
```

Everything works well except that when I do a post over my app, then the post looks different from a manual done post. In particular, there is an additional link under the users name saying "Test App" and when I click on it I am forwarded to the page of my fb app. Is there any way how I can prevent showing the name of my app when I post via an app, or is this not allowed by Facebook? In other words, I'd like that the post looks like the post done normally via the facebook page.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a security feature of the Graph API (and a featured designed to direct traffic to your application).  Unfortunately there is no way to suppress this behaviour.